# Heap corruption on windows manipulating array of pointers to structures in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

This code compiles fine on both windows (using VS2010) and Linux (using gcc). It runs fine on Linux, but on Windows I am getting heap corruption. What is going on?

The intent of the code is just to learn how to work with arrays of pointers to structures in C. It is just a toy example: you have a structure apple with a character array specifying the sort and a double, specifying the weight. Basket is a structure which holds an array of pointers to apples. The basket itself has some other parameters, e.g. showing how full is the basket and how many apples are in there.

I tried playing with the flags in VS and set it for compiling as a C code (/TC) but this didn't make a difference. So my questions are:

1. Is there something wrong with the code?
2. Why are the results different on Windows and Linux?

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Apple{
    char *Sort;
    double Weight;
};

struct Basket{
    struct Apple **apples;
    double full;
    int numApples;
};

int main()
{
    int i;
    int numApples = 5;

    struct Basket *mybasket = (struct Basket *) malloc(sizeof(structBasket*));
    struct Apple **apples;
    apples = malloc(numApples*sizeof(struct Apple*));

    for(i=0;i<numApples;i++)
    {
        apples[i] = (struct Apple*)malloc(sizeof(struct Apple*));
        apples[i]->Sort = (char *)malloc(18*sizeof(char *));
        apples[i]->Weight = ((double)i+1)*0.57;
    }

    mybasket->apples = apples;
    mybasket->full = 0.8;
    mybasket->numApples =numApples;

    strcpy(apples[0]->Sort, "Fuji");
    strcpy(apples[1]->Sort, "Braburn");
    strcpy(apples[2]->Sort, "Golden Delicious");
    strcpy(apples[3]->Sort, "Red Delicious");
    strcpy(apples[4]->Sort, "McIntosh");

    for(i=0;i < numApples;i++)
    {
        printf("\n apple #%d is %s and weights %f  pounds",i,mybasket->apples[i]->Sort,mybasket->apples[i]->Weight);
    }

    printf("\n\n");

    for(i=numApples-1;i>-1;i--)
    {
        free(apples[i]);
    }

    free(apples);
    free(mybasket);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Most of the places where you are calling `malloc` and passing in `sizeof(struct Whatever *)` you should instead be passing `sizeof(struct Whatever)`. You want the size of the structure, not the size of a pointer. The fact that it runs correctly on Linux is just luck.

Comment: You also need `free(apples[i]->Sort);` in the loop before `free(apples[i]);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Is there something wrong with the code?

Yes.

1. `struct Basket *mybasket = (struct Basket *) malloc(sizeof(structBasket*));` should be `struct Basket *mybasket = malloc(sizeof(structBasket));`
2. `apples[i] = (struct Apple*)malloc(sizeof(struct Apple*));` should be `apples[i] = (struct Apple*)malloc(sizeof(struct Apple));`
3. `apples[i]->Sort = (char *)malloc(18*sizeof(char *));` should be `apples[i]->Sort = malloc(18);`

Since `T *ptr` points to "an array" of `T`, the memory space called for should be `n * sizeof (T)`.

Also, to avoid a memory leak, `free()` all fields of a struct before `free()`ing it:

```
while(numApples--)
{
    free(apples[numApples]->Sort);
    free(apples[numApples]);
}
```

> 2. Why are the results different on Windows and Linux?

Because accessing memory not allocated yet invokes **undefined behaviour**, in which case anything from working as expected to a heap corruption can happen. It works on Linux simply because you are (un)lucky.

Comment: Thank you! The only thing I had to add is change the line allocating memory for apples along the same lines you suggested, namely: apples = malloc(numApples*sizeof(struct Apple)); I still like explicit casts, even though they are not necessary.